# An interesting limit

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials, convergence-divergence

> Let $x\in\mathbb{R}.$ For all $i,j\in\mathbb{N},$ define $a_{i0} = \frac{x}{2^i}, a_{ij} = a_{i,j-1}^2 + 2a_{i,j-1}.$ Find, with proof, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{nn}.$

Below is my attempt.
Let for each $n, p_n(x) = a_{nn}$. Then observe that $a_{n+1,n} = p_n(\frac{x}2).$ As well, $p_{n+1}(x)+1 = (p_n(\frac{x}2)+1)^2.$ Iterating gives $p_2(x) = ((p_0(\frac{x}4)+1)^2+1)^2, p_3(x) = (((p_0(\frac{x}8)+1)^2+1)^2+1)^2, p_n(x) = ((\dots (p_0(\frac{x}{2^n})+1)^2\dots)^2+1)^2,$ but I'm not sure how this can be converted to a more useful form such as $(1+\frac{x}{2^n})^{2^n}.$

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Consider $b_{ij} = a_{ij} + 1$ rather than $a_{ij}$. That simplifies things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ ,

$a_{n,0}=\frac{x}{2^n}$

$a_{n,1}+1=(a_{n,0}+1)^2=(\frac{x}{2^n}+1)^2$

$a_{n,2}+1=(a_{n,1}+1)^2=(\frac{x}{2^n}+1)^4$

Continuing this way,

For $1\le j\le n$,

$a_{n,j}+1=(\frac x{2^n}+1)^{2^j}$

Thus for $n=j$,

$a_{n,n}+1=(\frac x{2^n}+1)^{2^n}$

Taking limit as $n\to \infty$, we get

$lim_{n\to \infty} a_{n,n}+1=e^x$ ( Since the right limit is a subsequence of the sequence $(1+\frac xn)^n$ converging to $e^x$)

This gives required limit as $e^x-1$.